# Handlerbars.registerHelper issue with Ember 1.0 pre

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I just moved to Ember 1.0 pre and I am facing issues with EM.handlebars.registerHelper

I am using the handlebars helper defined [here](https://github.com/emberjs/examples/blob/master/contacts/app.js) :

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('editable', function(path, options) {
  options.hash.valueBinding = path;
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, App.EditField, options);
});
```

Like that :

```
{{#view App.CardView}}
  {{#with view.content}}
    {{editable name}}
  {{/with}}
{{/view}}
```

But instead of the value of *name*, I got *empty* and moreover the field is not editable.

If I write

```
{{#view App.CardView}}
  {{#with view.content}}
    {{name}}
  {{/with}}
{{/view}}
```

The name attribute is displayed.

Any thought ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of your example?